# Template function cannot be passed into std::transform directly

Tags: c++, templates

Given a vector of complex numbers, I want to get their absolute values:

```cpp
std::vector<std::complex<double>> in; // filling omitted
std::vector<double> out(in.size());
std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(),
                 &std::abs<std::complex<double>> // (1)
//                 [](std::complex<double> z){ return std::abs(z); } // (2)
               );
```

In my understanding, the lines (1) and (2) should have the same effect.

However, while line (2) compiles correctly, the line (1) producess an error:

```
../../../include/c++/12/bits/stl_algo.h:4263:31: error: cannot convert 'std::complex<double>' to 'double' in assignment
 4263 |         *__result = __unary_op(*__first);
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
      |                               |
      |                               std::complex<double>
```

Why do I get this error? Why is the anonymous function necessary here?

Comment: Interesting question! I think, that you have the `std::abs` template argument wrong. Looking at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/abs, it looks like it needs to be `double`, not `complex<double>`, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: Indeed, `abs` is templated on the `T` in the `complex<T>` parameter. Your instantiated prototype is `std::complex<double> abs(const std::complex<std::complex<double>>&)`.

Comment: Side note: Lambda version will be faster then version with pointer to function. It is hard to explain for beginners why it happens.

Comment: I guess future versions of std must define template functions as nebloids with costumization points.

Comment: [W.E.Brown on "template functions"](https://youtu.be/NIDEjY5ywqU?t=203).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The template argument of `std::abs<T>(std::complex<T>)` is the type `T` used to represent the `std::complex<T>`. You are instantiating `std::abs<std::complex<double>>` which returns a `std::complex<double>` but you want `std::abs<double>(const std::complex&)`.

For the details I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/abs and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex.

Picking the functions pointer via `std::abs<double>` will not work because `std::abs` is overloaded and taking its adress would require to pick the right overload via a `static_cast`. Moreoever, standard functions may not be taken their address unless they are explicitly addressable functions. Using the lambda is clearly the simpler alternative.